# Jupyter notebook: reloading does not change class interface

Tags: caching, ipython, jupyter-notebook

When I edit a method of a class that existed when I launched the jupyter notebook (adding a print statement or something), the new code will be executed. But when I add a new method to the class, I need to relaunch the jupyter notebook to use it. Otherwise, it says that the method is not defined. It does not matter if I execute the `import` statement another time.

So apparently the interface (i.e. defined methods) stays cached and only the content is reloaded. How can I reload everything?

I have installed the project in development mode and I use `%autoreload 2` in the notebook.